# Custom DependencyProperty not updating on animation

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am porting an application from Windows Phone 8 (Silverlight) to WinRT-XAML. I have created a custom `DependecyProperty` that I am animating using a DoubleAnimation. This worked just find on WP8, but does not work on the WinRT version.

The property itself does work; if I set its value manually in the code, the change callback is called and everything works. The animation seems to run as well; it lasts for the specified duration and then completes with the `AnimCompleted` callback - but the `DependencyProperty` is not updated nor is its change callback not called. I created a timer to print out the value of the animated property while the animation is running, and it stays constant.

What am I doing wrong? What is different on WinRT compared to WP8?

Property definition:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register( "MyProp", typeof(double), typeof(MyClass),
                                 new PropertyMetadata( 1d, OnMyPropChanged ));

public double MyProp
{
    get { return (double)GetValue( MyPropProperty ); }
    set { SetValue( MyPropProperty, value ); }
}

private static void OnMyPropChanged( DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
{
    var m = d as MyClass;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( "Value now: " + m.MyProp );
}
```

XAML:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="AnimSB" Completed="AnimCompleted">
    <DoubleAnimation x:Name="Anim" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MyProp" Duration="0:0:1.00">
        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
    </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

Code to start the animation:

```
MyProp = 2.0; // this causes a call to OnMyPropChanged just fine
Anim.From = 2.0;
Anim.To = 1.0;
Storyboard.SetTarget( Anim, this );
AnimSB.Begin();
// after this, MyProp stays constant, OnMyPropChanged is not called,
// and AnimCompleted is called after exactly one second.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set [`EnableDependentAnimation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.doubleanimation.enabledependentanimation.aspx) to true on the animation. The reason is to discourage animating properties that change on the UI thread (dependent properties) and thus produce choppy animations. It's recommended to only animate independent properties such as `RenderTransform` properties or `Opacity` and not dependent ones like `Width`, `Margin`, `Canvas.X` or custom properties.